# Make link unclickable with regex unless from the certain domain 

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, hyperlink

I want to write a regex which will make link unclickable - simply removing href html tags and leaving the link url as text. So it will ignore anchor text if it is given only leave the url.

But this regex should make links unclikable if they are not from the certain domain. I want this for my private messaging system.

So regex will do following

if the link is not targeting the certain domain make the link url text. Ignore given anchor text.

asp.net 4.0 , C# 4.0

Example

```
<a href="http://www.monstermmorpg.com/" target="_blank">My domain</a>
```

This will be parsed as `http://www.monstermmorpg.com/` it will be text

Comment: As with all regex related queries, please post sample data to test with, as well as expected results

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. [Ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works on jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(removeLink("domain.com"));

function removeLink(domain)
{
   $('a').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr("href")!=null)
       if($(this).attr("href").indexOf(domain)>=0)
           $(this).removeAttr("href");
})
}
```

Explanation:

Gets all anchor elements in the HTML rendered iterating through them and removing the `href` attribute of the hyperlink for all the the ones that have domain.com as part of it.

[jsfiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/J2E5k/20/)

Comment: actually it will remove all links expect given one.

Comment: thanks for comment. I solved problem with  htmlagilitypack :) but jquery would also work.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG my "UPDATE" had a bug, apparently. jsFiddle sometimes it's so slow that you think it ran your script and it worked but in reality it didn't. My initial example definitely works fine. I updated the link with several hyperlinks and even different paths on the same domain and it worked fine.